# Error de sockets 'connection refused: connect'

Tags: java, socket

Estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación cliente-servidor, este es el código del cliente:

```
try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.66", 9999);
        PrintWriter salida = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()), true);
        salida.println("Up");
        salida.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage());
    }
```

Y este el del servidor:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(9999);
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = servidor.accept();
            BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String order = entrada.readLine();
            System.out.println(order);
            if (order.equals("Up")) {
                upScore();
                socket.close();
            } else if (order.equals("Down")) {
                downScore();
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Ya me asegure de que el puerto `9999` esté abierto en mi módem.

Comment: Bienvenido JORGE, te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Comment: Y en tu server no tienes habilitado un firewall?

Comment: Esa excepción ocurre cuando no hay ningún servicio (servidor) abierto y escuchando en esa IP o puerto. Con el puerto no hay problema (ya que claramente se ve que ambos utilizan el puerto `9999`, pero ¿te aseguraste que la dirección IP `192.168.1.66` corresponda a la dirección IP donde el servidor se está ejecutando?

Comment: La diferencia puede ser si estás usando dos máquinas o una. Si es la misma te recomiendo conectarte a `localhost` en vez de la ip primero para verificar que la conexión en sí funcione. Si no es en una úbica pc, deberías de poner las ip's y posiblemente tu máscara de subred pra verificar que no esté mal configurada tu red.

Answer (score 2):

Por tus palabras entiendo que pretendes conectarte a través del módem es decir que pretendes que esa conexión salga de tu red local que tienes en casa, salga a internet a través de tu proveedor de servicios y se conecte al servidor.

Si es esto lo que estás intentando, la razón por la que no te funciona es porqué la ip a la que estás intentando acceder es una ip privada es decir del modem/router para dentro de tu casa.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direcci%C3%B3n_IP#Direcciones_privadas

Si lo que intentas es conectarte por ejemplo a casa de un amigo necesitarias saber la ip publica del modem/router de tu amigo, y se debería de configurar para permitir la conexión.

Si no es esto lo que estás intentando borrare la respuesta

Comment: No puedo dejar comentarios en respuestas quen o sean mias

Comment: no puedes por que ocupas 50 de reputación, pero no por eso es válido dejar comentarios en la zona de respuestas; deberás esperar y acumular dichos puntos ayudando en otras publicaciones

Comment: Entonces preferirias que algo que puede ayudar a alguien a saber lo que pasa me lo guarde, y no se lo comunique.

Comment: puedes mejorarlo aportando en la publicación la solución con el código del OP, por que ahi solo estas dando conceptos; no veo como lo solucione así

Comment: La solucion la aporto el codigo no está mal, esta mal la IP, debe de poner la ip publica del sitio donde se quiere conectar

Comment: entonces por ejemplo puedes explicarle de manera técnica como obtenerla, ok eso es lo que tiene mal; ahora dile exactamente como obtenerla

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89140/discussion-between-juan-and-element).